# Upgrade php in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, wamp

I am currently using wamp server with PHP version 5.3.13. I have read articles on the web which emphasize upgrading to version 5.5 as mysql will not be supported and mysqli/pdo will be from this version onwards.

Problem: I am unable to find a wamp server with php 5.5 (the [current one is 5.4](http://www.wampserver.com/en/php-addons/),)

Question: Do I need to upgrade my php version now? What would happen if I don't?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116940,117978#msg-117978

Comment: No. 5.3 supports mysqli and pdo just fine. That doesn't mean you can just keep on using mysql, because it WILL be removed from a future PHP version. But you don't need to upgrade just to use the new libraries.